# Étale cohomology and Picard group of curves

Tags: algebraic-curves, etale-cohomology

Say we have $X$ a smooth projective curves over $\mathbb{Q}$, then I know there is an isomorphism $H_{ét}^1(X\times_\mathbb{Q}\overline{\mathbb{Q}},\mathbb{G}_m)\cong Pic(X\times_\mathbb{Q}\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$. I am wondering about its properties.

First, we have a $G_\mathbb{Q}$-action on both sides, are they compatible?

And second, is it functorial in $X$?

I would appreciate references.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want $X$ to be defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Matt Let's say that $X$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then we make the base change to the algebraic closure.